# GRB 221009A Comparison with solar flare NOOA scale

Tags: astrophysics, estimation, gamma-rays, data, solar-wind

I'm trying to found a comparison of the energy received on Earth by GRB 221009A in comparison of various solar flares based on NOAA Space Weather Scales (or other).

I failed to find any comparison (like for example in comparison of a Carrington event). Does someone have such an information with a source?

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm not sure because Astronomy isn't really Astrophysics...

Comment: Are you wanting to compare the $\gamma$-ray spectra or the two? Or are you interested in the overall shape of the two energy spectra (even if in different energies)? And what troubles are you having in obtaining the data separately and comparing it yourself?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm looking to compare for the available data. Whatever the spectra. I'm having a trouble because i didn't found any information on Google (very likely i don't use the good keywords).

Comment: I'm not sure what you'll get out of the comparison then, since they originate from physically distinct processes. But searching `grb 221009A energy spectrum` yielded quite a few papers, though the actual numerical values they plot might require emailing the researchers involved. I didn't try, but I imagine a similar search for the solar flares would yield the results you want.

Comment: @VincentISOZ - The Wind KONUS instrument (https://wind.nasa.gov/data_sources.php#KONUS_Data) has databases of both GRBs and solar flares.  There are also the GCN (https://gcn.gsfc.nasa.gov) catalogues that provide these one-page summaries of the info for each GRB we observe/measure.